# Android apk compile to ART runtime and dalvik runtime

Tags: android, dalvik, art-runtime

Google added a new ART runtime with Android 4.4. How can I target my apk to both ART runtime and Dalvik runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This change is without consequences for the developers. Your app remains exactly the same, nothing to do there. Just make sure you target API 19 so that your app is available for KitKat users. They will decide in their phone if they want to use ART or Dalvik.

Comment: Wrong.. Whatsapp has failed to run with ART.

Comment: @Sachin: Please note that ART is still in development. So the fact that WhatsApp fails to run on it doesn't necessary means that you have something special to do.

Comment: Its not 100% cross-platform thing.. in case your app is directly interacting with VM behaviour..

Comment: Note: You don't need to target api 19 for the app to be available to KitKat users.

Comment: Agree to k3v1n4ud3. I'm quoting AOSP member on whatsapp issue from this google code thread  _"I'll reiterate that this is not the fault of the WhatsApp application. The ART verifier was blocking the installation of this app, but we are going to fix ART to address this issue. I'll update this bug when the fix is in AOSP."_ Details : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61792&q=whatsapp&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but very key.  I confirmed today, all my apps break with ART+Android-5 on Nexus-x tablets.  ART does more strict JNI checks, so if your app uses java plus native code,the move from Dalvik to ART may break app operation.  For me, it has been a complete show-stop.  I have 6 apps in Google Store and all fail now on Nexus devices running Android 5.x, yet they run correctly on all 4.x.x (Kitkat) series devices.  This is most frustrating.  I am going thru all the ART/ Dalvik questions and answers on this site.  ART and Android-5.x is *very* significant change, so the question asked here "How do I target my apk to both Dalvik and ART?" is a key and very critical question.  Time has proven that the responses given suggesting "No difference to developers" is manifestly incorrect.  It certainly is in our case.

Two specific issues are documented, and I quote from "Verifying App Behavior on the Android Runtime (ART)":

1) " Checking JNI code for garbage-collection issues
ART has a compacting garbage collector under development on the Android Open Source Project (AOSP). Once the compacting garbage collector is in use, objects may be moved in memory. If you use C/C++ code, do not perform operations that are incompatible with compacting GC. We have enhanced CheckJNI to identify some potential issues (as described in JNI Local Reference Changes in ICS)."    In other words, the new ART memory mangement model may break your existing (and operational) native code.

2) " Error handling
ART's JNI throws errors in a number of cases where Dalvik didn’t.".

A limited explanation of some of the issues that will cause errors to be thrown by the Android 5.x ART is provided in: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html#JNI_Issues

The forward-compatibility solution currently being adopted among users of Android devices running ART and 5.x, and facing non-operational apps, is a downgrade to Android 4.4.4, by unlocking the bootloader, wiping the device memory, and installing system image "Hammerhead", in the case of those running Nexus series tablets.  For Samsung tablets, a tutorial is available at: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/489071-tutorial-downgrade-samsung-galaxy-s5-5-0-4-4-kitkat.html

Answer (score 0):

The **dalvik** or **ART** is only the **runtime** in the Android. As an app developer, you don't have to care about these differences. All you have to care about is your app's API level which is describing the dependence of the Android OS version.

And in Android 4.4, **ART** is only a development which is **NOT** the default runtime even if the release note describing that **ART** will make app use less memory and run quickly. If you want to find the different, you can wait for the next version of Android. In the opensource, I found the **ART** has been setting the default runtime selection.

Answer (score 0):

For most apps ART will work just fine.

It is, however, not 100% compatible as something that work on Dalvik may not work on ART

Please visit this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html) for more information.