# Making an Android App ART Complaint?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-4.4-kitkat

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question. So please let me know before down voting the question. Since the introduction of `ART(Android Runtime)` in `4.4 (KitKat)` there have been bundles of apps which keep on crashing every single time whenever the virtual machine is selected to `ART`. So my question is: How do you make a app `ART` compliant. Is there some specific code that we need to use, changes in the manifest? What are the changes that we developers need to do to make a app run flawlessly on both `Dalvik` and `ART`. I researched a bit online but cannot find anything concrete as of yet.
Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android apk compile to ART runtime and dalvik runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952029/android-apk-compile-to-art-runtime-and-dalvik-runtime) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979855/how-art-virtual-machine-is-going-to-affect-existing-applications/19980024

Comment: @CommonsWare - Reading the link, there are no changes then.? we just keep the code as-is?

Comment: For most apps, that is correct. To put it another way, we have no official guidance on anything that needs changing. I can't rule out that if an app does something odd (e.g., messes around with loading DEX files at runtime) that there might be additional work needed, but right now, we wouldn't even know what that work is.

Comment: Considering the links, i am not 100% confident that there shall be no changes for developers. I would suggest that the question be kept open.

Comment: Also, if you have a specific problem (e.g. a crash with an app you wrote), ask a specific question about that.